# Python file not closing

Tags: python, file, file-io, python-2.7

I wrote a program to do some processing to a little bit big amount of data. Three steps are involved there:

1. Read data
2. Do Processing
3. Write Data to a file.

While running the code first two steps done successfully.(As data is huge for my laptop configuration, I am using swap space in linux to do the job).

Now the third step:
Data is written to file successfully. But my code get stuck at the line `feat.close()` (feat is the file pointer). When I open the file while the process is running complete data is being written, but my file is not closing.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import sys
import numpy as np
import posTagsToTriGramFrequency as pt
import itertools
import gc

if sys.argv[1] == '-h':
    print("Usage: ./featureSelection <n(authorLimit)> <k(SD weight)> <nGramSize> <folder>")
    sys.exit()

n = int(sys.argv[1])
k = int(sys.argv[2])
nGramSize = int(sys.argv[3])
folder = sys.argv[4]

print('reading features')
feat = open('../../../../dataDump/'+ folder +'/features.dump','r')
features = {}

tagsnGram = [tuple(x) for x in itertools.product(pt.getTags(), repeat=nGramSize)]

gramdict = {}
for gram in tagsnGram:
    gramdict[gram] = []

flag = 1
author = ''
for line in feat:
    if(line == '\n'):
        flag = 1
    elif flag == 1:
        author = line.split('/')[-1][:-1]
        print(line, end='')
        features[author] = gramdict.copy()
        flag = 0
    else:
        tagsFreq = iter(line.split())
        for tag in tagsnGram:
            features[author][tag].append(float(tagsFreq.next()))

feat.close()

print('Calculating waht to delete')

nflag = 0
kflag = 0
toDel = []
for tagGram in tagsnGram:
    nflag = 0
    for author in features:
        kflag = 0
        for doc in features[author][tagGram]:
            if doc == 0 : kflag += 1
            if kflag >= k:
                nflag += 1
                break
        if nflag >= n:
            toDel.append(tagGram)
            break

for item in toDel:
    for author in features:
        del features[author][item]

f = open('../../../../dataDump/'+ folder +'/tagsInfo.dump','w')
f.write('k:' + str(k) + ',\t n:' + str(n) + '\n')
f.write('Deleted tags:\n')
for item in toDel:
    f.write(str(item) + ' ')
f.write('\n\nSelected Tags:\n')
for tagGram in features.itervalues().next():
        f.write(str(tagGram) + ' ')
f.close()

print("Writing Back Features")
feat = open('../../../../dataDump/'+ folder +'/selectedFeatures.dump','w')
for author in features.keys():
    feat.write(author + '\n')
    print(author)
    for tag in features[author]:
        for doc in features[author][tag]:
            feat.write(str(doc) + ' ')
        feat.write('\n')
    feat.write('\n')
    del features[author]
    #gc.collect()
print('Closing File')
feat.close()
```

**See the last line. At my console `Closing file` is being printed but after that my code is stuck.**

My Console Output:

```
abhi@abhi-me~/Projects/workspace/irProject/completepythonbased/authAttrib (irProject)>>./featureSelection.py 35 125 3 3GramFreq
reading features
Ajit_Popat
Mukund_Mehta
Parajit_Patel
Priyadarshi
Kumarpad_Desai
Bhaven_Kacchi
Shantibhai_Agrawat
Pravin_Darji
Ankit_Trivedi
Sharad_Rawal
Tushar_Shukla
Chandrakant_Mehta
Jay_Vasavda
Dolat_Bhatt
Munindra
Mrugesh_Vaishnav
Kulinchandra_Yagnik
Zaverilal_Mehta
Priti_Shah
Vasant_Mistri
Vatsal_Vasani
Dinesh_Mistri
Devesh_Mehta
Dhaval_Mehta
Urvish_Kothari
Madhusudan_Parekh
Vihari_Chaya
Virendra_Kapoor
Mukul_Choksi
Joravarsinh_Jadav
Ashok_Dave
Nasir_Ismaeli
Joban_Pandit
Priyakant_Parikh
Sudarshan_Upadhyay
Gajendra_Shah
Altaf_Patel
Bhalchandra_Jani
Shashin
Hansal_Bhachech
Calculating waht to delete
Writing Back Features
Pravin_Darji
Ajit_Popat
Kulinchandra_Yagnik
Sharad_Rawal
Madhusudan_Parekh
Shantibhai_Agrawat
Gajendra_Shah
Hansal_Bhachech
Vihari_Chaya
Virendra_Kapoor
Sudarshan_Upadhyay
Priyadarshi
Tushar_Shukla
Dolat_Bhatt
Urvish_Kothari
Vasant_Mistri
Mukund_Mehta
Zaverilal_Mehta
Kumarpad_Desai
Vatsal_Vasani
Bhaven_Kacchi
Mrugesh_Vaishnav
Bhalchandra_Jani
Priyakant_Parikh
Chandrakant_Mehta
Mukul_Choksi
Joravarsinh_Jadav
Munindra
Joban_Pandit
Devesh_Mehta
Priti_Shah
Ankit_Trivedi
Dinesh_Mistri
Dhaval_Mehta
Ashok_Dave
Nasir_Ismaeli
Parajit_Patel
Jay_Vasavda
Altaf_Patel
Shashin
Closing File
^C
[1]+  Killed                  ./featureSelection.py 35 125 3 3GramFreq
```

Why this is happening?

*You can find the strace [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9rBcMmY_5QURmR5SnM4RlFPQnM/edit?usp=sharing).*

**Edit :**
I tried to print something after close and it is printing, means problem is in exiting the program. It is using about 3 GBs of RAM and 3 GBs of swap space @Justing. To fill this memory it took 10-20 minutes and to clear this memory I waited for about 2 hrs, I think there is a problem.  **I uploaded the strace above, please see.**

Comment: It's worth noting that when working with files in Python, the best practice is to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4&lc=abvyzpzCoB4yV2md5OqJQZgXTd00VmErxY868GfWsEo&lch=email&feature=em-comment_received&lcor=1).

Comment: The code looks fine to me. If the file is huge, it's possibly just waiting for the OS to flush something to disk, or move pages in or out of swap, or somesuch. Have you tried just waiting for a while after the "Closing File" to see if it ever terminates by itself?

Comment: Run the program with `strace` to see what happens.

Comment: I waited for about more than 2 hrs.. still nothing

Comment: It seems very unlikely that closing a file takes a noticeable amount of time. Try printing something _after_ the `close()` statement to check that it's really the close that hangs.

Comment: What is your RAM usage? Programs that take forever to close sometimes are deconstructing large objects (or a whole lot of items) that are in swap.

Comment: I tried to print something after close and it is printing, means problem is in exiting the program. It is using about 3 GBs of RAM and 3 GBs of swap space @Justing. To fill this memory it took 10-20 minutes and to clear this memory I waited for about 2 hrs, I think there is a problem.  __I uploaded the strace in the question, please see.__

Comment: What version of Python are you running?  Scratch that, noticed the tags.  Is there any discrepancy with the output to file?

Comment: Version :  2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1]

Comment: @glglgl how can one run `strace` on .py script ?

Comment: @0x90 `strace python foo.py` or `strace ./foo.py`?

Comment: Very strange. The only other thing I can think of is that the script is using all the RAM and all the swap, and some untested call to `malloc()` is failing, which is causing undefined behavior. You may have to resort to running Python through a debugger to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Aya Half of the swap is still free.

Comment: No idea, then. Try the usual debugging approaches, like removing chunks of code until it works, or try it with a smaller input file or somesuch.

Answer (score 2):

Try to work with `with` which will flush to disk when you are done writing:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read()
f.closed
```

see the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). It should solve most of the problems when writing and reading from files.